# RichFaces: How to reset page in datascroller after changes of values in dataTable

Tags: jsf, pagination, richfaces, datascroller

I have `rich:datascroller` for my `rich:dataTable` which is working well except that when I am on any page number (let say 5) and do a search operation (or any operation which renders the dataTable). Pagination will still show page 5, but I want it to be reset to 1. page when the operation happens.

In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHBhK.png), when I am going to Page 5 and hit Search again or do a clear and search again, the pagination is still set to Page 5, not back to Page 1.

Here's my code snippet:

```
<rich:datascroller id="prodDataScroller" for="prodClassificationOutputTable"
                   rows="100"   maxPages="10" fastStep="3" renderIfSinglePage="false"
                   immediate="false" page="#{prodClassificationBean.firstPage}">
</rich:datascroller>

<rich:dataTable id="prodClassificationOutputTable" border="0"
                width="100%" columnClasses="col" headerClass="column-header"
                style="overflow:auto;" rowClasses="odd,even" align="center"
                value="#{prodClassificationBean.outputClassificationWrappers}"
                var="prodClassificationRow" rows="100" rowKeyVar="row" immediate="true">
<!-- ... -->
<rich:dataTable>
```

I checked other solutions. I tried to implement `page` attribute for datascroller but it doesn't seem to be working. I created an attribute `firstpage` in backing bean being set to "1" when search happens so that page attribute of datascroller will have value as 1. But it's not resolving the issue.

I would like to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I tried solutions from https://developer.jboss.org/thread/10566?start=0&tstart=0 but nothing is working

Comment: 1. This isn't an error.  2. You wrote that "nothing is working" from jboss forum, but you pasted here "an answer" which is the 3rd answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by myself. Here is what I did:

```
<rich:datascroller id="prodDataScroller" for="prodClassificationOutputTable"
                   rows="100" maxPages="10" fastStep="3" renderIfSinglePage="false"
                   binding="#{prodClassificationBean.scroller}">     
</rich:datascroller>
<rich:dataTable id="prodClassificationOutputTable" border="0" width="100%" 
                columnClasses="col" headerClass="column-header" 
                style="overflow:auto;" rowClasses="odd,even" align="center"
                value="#{prodClassificationBean.outputClassificationWrappers}"
                var="prodClassificationRow" rows="100" rowKeyVar="row" immediate="true">

    <rich:column align="center" width="20%">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="ID" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText style="font-weight:bold" value="#{prodClassificationRow.outputId}"/>
    </rich:column>

</rich:dataTable>
```

Among all, important to note is `binding="#{prodClassificationBean.scroller}"` in datascroller.

Now in the backing bean:

```
public class ProdClassificationBean {
    private transient HtmlDatascroller scroller; 
    //getter and setter for scroller

    // inside the action operation()
    if (scroller != null) {
        scroller.setPage("1");
    }
} // end of class
```